# Optimizing search in CFArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, optimization, search, binary-search

I have sorted CFArray, and I need to find the index of a value. But I am also not sure if the value is in this array, so I need to know this too.

Right now I use this code:

```
NSInteger valueIndex;
    BOOL valueExactMatch = CFArrayContainsValue((CFArrayRef)sortedBorders, arrayRange, value);
    if (valueExactMatch)
        valueIndex = CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue((CFArrayRef)sortedBorders, arrayRange, value);
    else
        valueIndex = CFArrayBSearchValues((CFArrayRef)sortedBorders, arrayRange, value, (CFComparatorFunction) CFDateCompare, nil);
```

But as I understand, valueExactMatch is being calculated twice — once in CFArrayContainsValue, and once performing the actual search.

Can I optimize it using existing CFArray implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue` returns -1 if there is no match, so you can use this like so:

```
NSInteger valueIndex = CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue((CFArrayRef)sortedBorders, arrayRange, value);
if (valueIndex == -1)
    valueIndex = CFArrayBSearchValues((CFArrayRef)sortedBorders, arrayRange, value, (CFComparatorFunction) CFDateCompare, nil);
```

I don't have a machine with XCode handy, but this may also work:

```
Boolean found = false;
NSInteger valueIndex = CFArrayBSearchValues((CFArrayRef)sortedBorders, arrayRange, value, (CFComparatorFunction) CFDateCompare, nil);
if (valueIndex < CFArrayGetCount(sortedBorders) && CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sortedBorders, valueIndex) == value)
  found = true;
```

Comment: Doesn't it perform two whole binary searches? It seems it should be even slower, isn't it?

Comment: In your code, you are searching the array once to get valueExactMatch, and then once again to get an index using either `CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue` or `CFArrayBSearchValues`.  In my code, I search once for the index and if it's found, its done.  It only searches a second time if there is no match.